# CLAHE algorithm explanation

Tags: java, image, algorithm, contrast

Is there any site with a complete explanation of the CLAHE algorithm, and maybe some sample code.
So far I have only found the code for matlab with no explanation and I need to implement my own (preferably in java).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

some basic explanation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization

and a code example:

http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/clahe/index.html

click on        "CLAHE_.java" for the code.